# How to use simple_form with a gem to select state/province and city one a country is selected?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I am looking to a find a solution to select in a form, based on country selected (which works well) one of the states or provinces of the selected country and once the state is selected, one of the cities in that state to be selected further.

I am looking at this gem  (since others I found are not a match for Rails 5).

```
https://github.com/loureirorg/city-state/issues
```

Or is someone else has a better solution I am looking to use it.

Comment: Well I don't know if there's a gem (nor am I sure it's the type of question SO will answer) but you can do this yourself with Javascript.  You have the 'city' drop down show up and populate only when a country is selected - heck I've seen ones that you select the country - if it's the US you get state and then a list of cities as well after you select the states - it's just javascript / AJAX queries based on the change of the 'parent' dropdown

Comment: Yes, there is a gem.

Comment: https://github.com/loureirorg/city-state

Comment: However my attempts based on the recommendations found over there did not work and I don't know how to improve my JavaScript.

Comment: What javascript have you tried?  You can use on change to trigger an ajax call to the next information